# SQL add extra input field for user

Tags: sql, alter-table

So you have the first table name jobs

| id | name | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | job1 | my notes |
| 2 | job2 | my notes |

Then I have a second table name extra_fields
where jobs_id(foreign key)

| id | jobs_id | extra_field | extra_field2 | extra_field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | new data | new data2 | null |
| 12 | 2 | null | null | new data3 |

So what I want is the user should be apple to make a extra_field4(a new column) if needed for some new data.

Don't no if this the best way to go around it, so when user want an extra input field, in the background make this code

```
ALTER TABLE extra_fields

ADD extra_field4 varchar(255);
```

The user will only see a html page where the user should be apple to add new "extra_fields"?

Hope it make sense, at the end make some restructure in db?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can add column by next command:

```
ALTER TABLE extra_fields ADD COLUMN extra_field4 varchar(255);
```

[sqlize](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/48355f25ec10e5208d31c788ecdd70b5/)

But in common case prefer to use easy extendable [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) architecture:

```
CREATE TABLE extra_fields (
    job_id int,
    field_name varchar(64),
    field_value varchar(64)
);
```

This approach enable to expand data without DB structure changes